# Responsive gif integration issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I’m a bit of a noob in css and I’m trying to integrate an animated gif as a smartphone screen with the help of bootstrap as I need it to be responsive.
I could make it work for large and medium screens, but when it comes to small displays when my container get resized it breaks.

I made a codepen (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGddKK) to demonstrate my attemp but as it breaks on small screens only I also made a screenshot of it outside codepen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/972nr.jpg).

Here's the code of the interesting part :

```
<div class="container position-relative">
    <img class="gif position-absolute img-fluid d-block mx-auto my-auto" src="mygif.gif" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto my-auto" src="phone.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who knows what’s happening and that can help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite your container width. 
Use below code in html or css file to get it work right.

```html
<style>
        @media (min-width: 576px) {
            .container {
                max-width: 100% !important;
            }
        }
</style>
```